# Hindi/ Devanagari tts for android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, hindi

I am planning to make an android app.
I wish to know if there is any tts engine that can read hindi/devanagari text. 
If not, 
Also, is there any tts engine that can read phonetics. If so is there a software that can convert hindi to engilish phonetics. Then I can have my tts engine read the phonetics.

Answer (score 0):

The native TTS on Android does not support Hindi. What you may have to do is create a service that uses the Hindi text and translates it to an audio file. You would then stream the audio file to your Android application.

No - the built-in Pico TTS provides only French, Italian, German, Spanish, and English (US and UK).

also check:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tts-for-android/_1-JG149quw